# Querying on existing query result mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I'm trying to do this:

```
const queryResult = model.findOne({some conditions})

const queryResultTwo = queryResult.find({some conditions})
```

But I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: queryResultTwo.find is not a function
```

How do I query on an existing query result? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since queryResult is not a collection, .find() is not going to work.
The basic syntax of the find() method is as follows −

```
db.COLLECTION_NAME.find()
```

Since I don't know the conditions I can suggest this - You can use the queryResult's data in the condition for the second find query